# Can't update GtkIconView from within a click event on a GtkListBox in a GtkDialog

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, gtk3, glade

Here's what the click event currently looks like for the ListBox in the dialog code.

```
def OnSelectCategory(self, listbox, data=None):

try:  
    # Get the text of the selected category.
    selected = listbox.get_selected_row()    
    label = selected.get_child()  
    itemText = label.get_text() 
            
    # Get the tags for the selected category.
    tagtext = self.categoryTags.get(itemText)            

    self.updateStatusbar("Collecting videos...")

    # Start a thread to scan for videos.
    self.threadEvent = threading.Event()
    self.videoscanThread = threading.Thread(target=self.ScanForVideos, args=(self.threadEvent, tagtext,))
    self.videoscanThread.daemon = True
    self.videoscanThread.start()

    self.threadEvent.set()

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception from 'OnSelectCategory':", str(e))
```

At first, I could not get the status bar to update the text immediately.  I had originally called the function to update the text directly.  The status bar text would not update until the ScanForVideos function had finished.  So, I moved the ScanForVideos code into a thread.  The thread waits on an event to begin.

The thread (ScanForVideos) runs several 'for' loops looking for a matching condition.  When the condition is found, the code appends to the liststore for the IconView.  At the end of the thread function, the code sets the IconView model to the liststore.  The IconView seems to update with a few items, but, not all that should be there.  Additionally, the code seems to be 'hung' because I cannot dismiss the dialog that contains the IconView.  I have to stop debugging within Visual Studio Code.

I feel like I'm violating something I'm not aware of in Python coding.  Or, my design to update the IconView is not correct.  Can anyone shed some light on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was trying to update some UI widgets from within my background thread.  I then stumbled upon [GLib.idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html).  I wrote a separate function to update the UI widgets and called idle_add passing the name of the function.  This allowed me to update the GUI from a background thread.